# Don't round-up tag-score count

Tags: feature-request, tags

Today I noticed I have 2k tag-score for [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). My First thought: Did I miss getting a gold badge?

But no, hovering over it I see that I only have 1539 tag score. The display gets rounded up. IMO this is confusing and should only display 2k if I really have at least 2k.

[image: Tag score count]

Comment: Displaying 1k is misleading though too. You say 'I don't want rounding', well then come up with a better solution that will work for people with high counts like Mr. Skeet too!

Comment: Just display the number in thousands. If I have 1500 - display 1k. If I have 3500 - 3k. I thought that was clear.

Comment: Meh. The exact information is available when needed, and this method of rounding is pretty standard. I like it as-is.

Comment: Maybe if you have 3,549, say 3.5k. If you have 3,550, say 3.6k. Essentially round to the nearest hundred instead of thousand.

Comment: I agree with @ColeJohnson. That works very well for rep, and it can at most have a rounding error of <10%, not 30% as we see in this case. Regarding Richard J. Ross' comment...if Jon Skeet's rounded rep can have four digits, surely we can allow juergen d's mysql tag score to have two?

Comment: You get the gold badge at 1k... http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/123/mysql?userid=575376

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I thought I get a gold badge for **every** 1k score. But seems to be awarded only once. My bad.

Answer (score 8):

Any good system should display at least two significant figures, for this very reason.

I recommend changing `nK` (e.g. `2K`) to `n.nK` (e.g. `1.6K` or `2.4K`), in much the same way that, for tens of thousands, we don't say `n0K` (`10K`, `20K`), but rather `nnK` (`14K`, `24K`).