# Does "k" really mean 1000?

Tags: support, views

Due to this question and answer [What are “kviews”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55109/what-are-kviews), I assume 1k = 1000, 2k= 2000...

I don't believe it. Or maybe I am wrong. Please check the below images.

> [image: Custom Date Format for Bootstrap-DatePicker 2 kviews]

You will see **2kviews**. But when you navigate to it, the actual view count is **15xx**.

> [image: Custom Date Format for Bootstrap-DatePicker viewed 1572 times]

What is going on? Is it a bug?

Comment: It is rounded to 2k.

Comment: @ juergen d, if so , do you mean 1001 views = 2k views ?

Comment: @Cataclysm no, 1501 views = 2K

Comment: By the way, you can hover over the "2 kviews" to see the actual number. :)

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, yes ! I had not notice that.

Comment: @Cataclysm - You do not need to give space between `@` and username. See [how does comment reply work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: I assume 2k means 2000 and over. As facebook like count.

Comment: @Cataclysm friendly warning: don't compare Stack Overflow with Facebook in your posts, it's a sensitive spot for many people here. :-D

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard No ,   I don't compare. Ah... I would like to describe well-known format.Just for an example. Hmm... has any Standard Syntax for it ? Sorry ! but I really thanks to you.

Comment: In case your not familiar of the route of the K as a short hand for thousand this question [explains where it comes from](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/112250/53561)

Comment: Given that privaledges are so much and more the 2k == 2k+ always made more sense to me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The number gets rounded to full thousands

```
999  views -> 999 views
1000 views -> 1k views
1499 views -> 1k views
1500 views -> 2k views
2499 views -> 2k views
```

[Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190698/dont-round-up-tag-score-count)

Comment: Is there any reason behind structure?

Comment: @Praveen what exactly do you expect instead of this?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - May be: 1501 -> 1.5, 2800 -> 2.8, 2499 -> 2.5 (i.e. same as user's reputation display on the post.)

Comment: @hims056 sounds like a valid feature request!

Comment: @hims056 , agree. I assume it is right way or rounded way. If so user will not ambiguous on it and may get more exact info.

Comment: @hims056 They actually do it that way with millions, so it certainly would make sense to handle thousands the same

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: [Rounding, round half away from zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero)?

Answer (score 6):

It is a rounded number, for example, 1501 would be rounded to 2K, as would say, 2499.  All rounded to the nearest thousand.