# Can we round up questions views with decimal values?

Tags: feature-request, views

At present views on any questions list page are round up by non decimal values

i.e.

> 1400 -> 1k,
>    1501 -> 2k

which makes [some confusions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207993/187824). Can we have round up with decimal values as well like:

> 1400 -> 1.4k,
>    1549 -> 1.5k,
>    2951 -> 3k,
>    323858 -> 323.9k

Same as we show user's reputation round up in any posts?

So if the views on [interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/) are 2549 it should show:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

or if the views on [questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) are 323,858 it should show:

[image]

instead of

[image]

<sub>Note: We may not apply this on questions with more than 100,000 views on [month](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month), [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/) etc tabs due to design issue.</sub>

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190698/dont-round-up-tag-score-count)

Comment: @juergend - Yes. And [answer by Emrakul](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190718/187824) is what I mean.

Comment: +1 but is it really that necessary? if you display a 150 titles on one page it's going to look really messy with all the decimal precisions

Comment: Scientific notations FTW!

Comment: @mehow - I don't think it will look messy. However AFAIK we can see maximum 50 questions per page on any [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) or [unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tab. And 100 on interesting tab.

Comment: i didn't mean 150 literally => "a lot", ok?

Comment: @mehow +1 for "is it really that necessary" - I don't see this as at all important.

Answer (score 5):

I favor this idea for the first example given with a low total number of views, but not for second case with a large number of views.  There is a 33% difference between 1500 and 2000 views yet they are represented the same, so the decimal value would add significant data.  On the other hand specifying **323.5k** instead of **324k** only adds visual clutter.

I propose that the decimal form shall be used for all values under 10,000.